# Why was this edit, which added a link, rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit, reject-reasons

Why was [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30937532) rejected?

Two reviewers rejected it with this reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

But I only added why the change the OP suggested was necessary and a link to another SO post. I only developed a bit what the OP meant. The link has two good answers which explain what the OP meant.

Then why was it rejected? Was it because the answer was wrong, and so something else should've been done rather than editing it (?)?

Comment: The question for which the answer you suggested an edit to, should be closed. It lacks debugging details.

Comment: Most often when you edit in a link that points to another question which has the same issue / the same answer, you should consider voting / flagging to close the question as a duplicate. That's how it's done on SO.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder *Why are mods so interested in deleting my comments?* -- Chatty comments are most often flagged **by normal users with flagging privileges** as "No longer needed". It may as well not always be the moderators. If you have clarifying information regarding your question please use the [edit] feature. It should not be added via comments, but directly edited into the question.

Comment: I think the title is misleading. It can be read as if you *only* added a link. You also added *"because you're importing the PyGame library, which also has a file with the same name"*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Don't try to [make a grain of sand into a tiny pearl](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). Just as it's [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to try to answer questions that don't meet the site standards, it isn't helpful to find a question that was asked in 2014, more or less completely ignored until 2022, given a bad answer (that, based on the available information, mis-diagnosed the problem)... and try to improve the answer. Especially when the question seems likely to have been caused by a typo (e.g. missing an `import` statement entirely) or by some other common problem (e.g. installing Pygame for the wrong Python installation). If the question had value, it would have either been properly answered or closed as a duplicate by that point.
2. Related to that: why are only asking now about your edit that was proposed and promptly rejected in January of 2022, more than a year ago?
3. Only add links to answers that link to other Stack Overflow Q&A, to explain points made incidentally in stride. If the link substantively explains the entire problem, then you have essentially identified a proposed duplicate Q&A. Duplicate questions should be closed as duplicates, not answered; and their answers are not improved by adding links to the canonical - what we want is to route the *question* to the canonical, since that also automatically redirects non-logged-in users.
4. For future reference: the best canonical I know of for the mis-identified problem (and I have seen no serious contenders) is [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353) . Since that question is also about ways to solve the problem rather than just why it occurs, it answers the question in the link that you found; so I went ahead and dupe-hammered that. As it happens, a couple weeks ago I added an answer there to attempt to be more thorough about solutions (including ways that avoid renaming the problematic file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was randomly going through all my rejected edits, as only now did it strike me that 28 suggestions were *rejected*, as I don't think I had been notified, either. And how do some users get deleted/get the usernames replaced by 'user...'? What happened to richardec (a high-rep user)?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder When you see a regular non-spammer user being deleted, that is almost definitely them personally requesting for it to happen.

Comment: Ah. No, normally you don't get notified about rejected edits; the only reason there is a notification for accepted edits is because of the reputation gain.

Comment: the site doesn't send out notifications for a lot of important events. You have to keep an eye on your user CP yourself to really be knowledgeable of what is going on. I have been doing so myself when I noticed that several of my flags had been declined in a short period of time. That was my first "whoops, I'm doing something wrong" moment that I was completely oblivious to until I took the time to go look.